# Views slideshow with two pagers

Tags: 7, views

I want to have a views slideshow as the following:

- Two content types which one has image field and the other has video field.
- I need to have two pagers for the slideshow, one pager for content type (**image**) and one for content type(**video**).

I searched for a solution but i couldn't fine one, also tried to make the pager as a views then using views field view module but no luck.

This photo will explain what i looking for:
[image]

Any tips?
Thanks

Comment: at present no module have this option, you have to create a new with the help of node gallery module

Comment: As I'm looking at this, I wonder how you imagine the auto advance working.  Generally speaking, the pager is a queue for the main area, you effectively have 2 queues driving it and I'm curious how that would work.

Either way I really suspect this would be custom work

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using three views.

1. Make the center part of the screen a view which uses a URL argument to know which node to pull the image/video from.
2. Make the listing of possible photos a view. Make each link to view #1 and passes in the node id.
3. Make the listing of possible videos a view. Make each link to view #2 and passes in the node id.

To put all three views on one page you have several options. You could use the module Panels or make each view a block and put them into different regions.

Comment: Sorry but what you mean about "Make each link to view #1 and passes in the node id." ?

Comment: I created 2 views one for the center part and the second for video pager, when the url change with the new nid the views slideshow does not change the content.

Comment: You need to add an "Views Argument" to the slideshow. https://drupal.org/node/54455.